# Deploying to Apple Watch: iPhone minimum version error

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

My iPhone is running iOS 8.3 (`8.3 (12F70)` according to "General/About"). Yet, when I try to deploy my Apple Watch app, I see "The system version is lower than the minimum OS version specified...Have 8.2; need 8.3"

The exact error message from my device log is:

```
<Warning>: failed to install WatchKit application, error: (Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x14531410 {Error=DeviceOSVersionTooLow, ErrorDescription=The system version is lower than the minimum OS version specified for bundle at /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.nfvRfP/extracted/com.mycompany.WatchKitCatalogDemo.watchkitapp.app. Have 8.2; need 8.3})
```

I'm running Xcode 6.3.1, which should have the 8.3 SDK, so I don't think it's that.

Has anyone seen this error?

Comment: Are you targeting 8.3?

Comment: Whether I set `MinimumOSVersion` in `info.plist` to 8.2 or 8.3, I get the same message. It's like there's some "8.2" string hanging around somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: Perhaps its hanging around in derived data somewhere? Is that possible? Maybe do a clean, and wipe that data. Reset your device, unplug, etc.